# delta live tables aggregations in gold layer

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, change-data-capture, delta-live-tables

In our DLT gold layer we have some aggregation queries that are live so it computes the whole thing. We would like to make this quicker and use CDF for business level aggregates like below

https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/delta-lake-cdf.html

We are thinking along the lines of only computing aggregations for the changes and merging to gold layer . for which
I need to find out what has changed in a delta table after a dlt pipeline has run and then do aggregations for the changes and merge to the gold layer?Similar to the link (https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/delta-lake-cdf.html)

From what I see DLT overwrites the whole table? How can I accomplish this using DLT

Kind Regards
Priya